# Use of "Trivially True" in math

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, terminology

Trivial, according to [Google dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=trivial%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS877US877&ei=1rIuYviXK43eau6am8AL&oq=tr&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIICC4QsQMQgwEyCAgAEIAEELEDMg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARCjAjIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoICAAQsQMQkQI6BQgAEJECOgUIABCABEoECEEYAEoECEYYAFCYAViGMmD5PmgFcAF4AIABUogBkAeSAQIxNJgBAKABAbABAMgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) is an adjective with the meaning "of little value or importance." Some synonyms include: unimportant, insignificant, inconsequential, etc. It appears the literal meaning does not apply in math, because [Triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triviality_(mathematics)) or [Trivially true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ATrivially_true#:%7E:text=The%20term%20is%20also%20often,%3D4%20%27%20is%20trivially%20true.) means different things in different contexts making it more confusing. In simple language, what does the term mean?

Comment: I think the wiki article you link to on triviality gives a nice characterization with examples. I am not sure what you are looking for beyond that. The usage is context dependent in some sense. Moreover, one should be aware of one's audience; what is "trivial" to one audience may not be so to another. As with other vocabulary, I think the best way to get a sense of its usage is to read a lot, after which you will inevitably encounter many examples.

Comment: Generally, "trivial" or "trivially true" can be essentially thought of as meaning "obvious at a glance or with little thought in mind", and a "trivial situation" is one of little importance. As noted above though, it depends on context. What I might consider a triviality worth omitting from proofs in my graduate analysis classes, I might not consider such in the class I'm teaching on calculus.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the word trivial has essentially two different uses in math. One of its uses is for an argument or step in a proof that the author doesn't explicitly justify because they consider it clear or obvious, e.g. "It is trivial to show that...". I think it's important to be careful when using it like this, because what is obvious to one person may not be obvious to another. The second use is for an extremely simple and uninteresting example of a class of objects. There are many examples of this from the Wikipedia page you link, including the trivial one-element group, the empty set, or the trivial solution to a linear system (all variables are zero). An example of this usage might be "This result holds for all non-trivial groups."